# Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects

```
Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  Stack Trace: 
    DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.CreateProxyObject(Type memberType, IElementLocator locator, IEnumerable`1 bys, Boolean cache)
    DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.Decorate(MemberInfo member, IElementLocator locator)
    PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator)
    PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator)
    PageFactory.InitElements(ISearchContext driver, Object page)
```

chrome is loaded successfully but the error is in login

[SetUp]

```
public void Setup()
{
    PropertiesCollection.Driver = new ChromeDriver();

    PropertiesCollection.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://XXX");
    

}
```

[Test]

```
public void ExecuteTest()
        {

                        //login using Page object Model
            LoginPageObject pageLogin = new LoginPageObject();
            DashboardPageObject Dashboard = pageLogin.Login();

            Dashboard.NavigateToSecurity();


        }
```

Comment: To help you, probably it will be necessary to know how you are managing your dependencies and the code related to this interface.

Comment: Please add more information like , what code caused the error ,  is it compilation error , run time error etc. When asking a question make bit it more descriptive. as mentioned by @JoãoFarias add information like are you using any build tools like maven , add a simple reproducible example also

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resolved when uninstall selenium.webdriver and selenium.support and install it again

Comment: Can you expand on this answer at all? It uninstalling the only option? Something strikes me as checking for older versions and upgrading them would also solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium.Webdriver 4.0 at least, you need to install both Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support packages (same version).